# Estimating integrals involving $\pi(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, definite-integrals, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

While solving an exercise in analytic number theory, I ran into difficulty of estimating an integral of the form $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\pi(t)}{t} dt$ where $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)

I am interested in understanding how to estimate this integral (as a function of $x$ of course), whether it is a [big Oh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) estimate, or something more precise. Any references are appreciated.

Similarly, how would one estimate $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} dt$  as a function of $x$?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it alright to use known estimates of $\pi(t)$, like Chebyshev's theorem or the prime number theorem?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Chebyshev's Theorem is alright :) But I would prefer to avoid PNT since we are not there yet in the course.

Comment: Since $\pi(t) = O(t/\log t)$ by Chebyshev, why not just replace $\pi(t)$ by $t/\log t$ in the integrands to get a big-$O$ upper bound?

Comment: @GregMartin: Wow that's so simple! Thanks a lot. Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: It's a bit interesting that $\int_1^x \pi(t)/t\,dt \sim \pi(x)$ :)

Comment: $$\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} = \frac{\pi(x)}{x} + \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} dt$$ So you only need Merten's theorem, much weaker than PNT, to get $$\int_2^\infty \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2}dt = \log\log x - \frac{\pi(x)}{x} + \mathcal{O}(1)$$ which is essentially an analogue of the above asymptotics by @AntonioVargas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting to add to the answers already appearing in the comments, and so that the question does not remain unanswered.

By the prime number theorem $$\int_1^x \frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt = \int_1^x \frac{1}{\log t}dt+O\left(\int_1^x \frac{1}{\log^2 t}dt\right)$$ $$=\frac{x}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2 x}\right).$$ Using Chebyshev's bounds instead of the PNT allows us to show that the integral is $O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right).$

To be more precise, we may note that $$\int_1^x \frac{\pi(t)}{t} dt=\sum_{p\leq x} \log(x/p).$$ This is a basic example of Riesz weights. Then we have that $$\sum_{p\leq x} \log x =\log x \text{li}(x)+O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$$ where $\text{li}(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t}dt$, and $$\sum_{p\leq x} \log p = \theta(x)=x+O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right).$$ Hence $$\int_1^x \frac{\pi(t)}{t} dt=\log x \text{li}(x)-x +O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$$ which implies that $$\int_1^x \frac{\pi(t)}{t} dt=\frac{x}{\log x}+\frac{2x}{\log^2 x}+\cdots .$$